# Long running job

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am not sure what is going on? I still get an email even though the job stopped running at 11:50 pm which clearly is less than thean 7 hours being that it started at 7 pm last night..It is suppose to email me if the job runs longer than 7 hours and for some reason yesterday it worked in test but today its not..Any ideas???

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb..sysjobactivity aj
JOIN msdb..sysjobs sj on sj.job_id = aj.job_id
WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,aj.start_execution_date,GetDate())> 7
AND aj.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL 
AND sj.name = 'Nightly_Job'
and not exists ( -- make sure this is the most recent run 
select 1 
from msdb..sysjobactivity new 
where new.job_id = aj.job_id 
and new.start_execution_date > aj.start_execution_date)
if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
USE msdb
            EXEC sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'DB_Mail',
                @recipients = 'xxx@yyy.com',
                @subject = 'T-SQL Query Result',
                @body = 'The Nightly_Job has been running 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that it only checks how long has passed since the job was started... it doesn't take into account when the job completed.

If there are no other executions of the job within 7 hours, then your check that limits the query to the most recent run doesn't exclude the previously completed job... your query then returns the job that was started over 7 hours ago, but in this case completed within 4 hours.

To fix your query to exclude completed jobs, modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    msdb..sysjobactivity aj
    JOIN msdb..sysjobs sj on sj.job_id = aj.job_id
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, aj.start_execution_date, 
            ISNULL(aj.stop_execution_date, GetDate()) )> 7 
    AND sj.name = 'Nightly_Job'
    AND NOT EXISTS ( -- make sure this is the most recent run 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM msdb..sysjobactivity new 
        WHERE new.job_id = aj.job_id 
        AND new.start_execution_date > aj.start_execution_date)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! That totally worked!How are you using the IS NULL THOUGH? Shouldn't there be a non null value there since the job had stopped?

Comment: I understand! I needed to exclude or have the jobs be null as they are the ones that have not finished yet...

Comment: @Sputnicktheproducer You're welcome.  I think you already got it, but the `ISNULL` causes the query to compare the start date to the end date if there is one, or compare the start date to the current time if the job has not yet finished...